# Getting out of the ooze pit in Tanaan Jungle without flying?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So, I still haven't unlocked Draenor Flying yet.

Is there any way to get out of the giant ooze pit surrounding Hellfire Citadel without flying, or do you just need to use an item to port out?

Comment: Note: There is a large amount of player clipping in this area, so even if it *looks* like you can get out, you may not be able to.

Answer (score 2):

There are several areas where you can climb out without flying. Notably, near the bridge to Hellfire Citadel on the eastern edge of the pit. However, you're probably better off Hearthing as being in the slime causes damage and at 10 stacks you die.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesnt damage you use a heartstone. If it does damage but doesnt kill you find a save spot if there is none take off your gear.

Else try to reset your location through help. 
If you cant becausr of damage go to the website and reset from there through yor account